# The definition of term in Enderton's Logic book

Tags: logic, first-order-logic

In page 74 of Enderton's book *A Mathematical Introduction to Logic* (Second Edition), Enderton defines term as follows:

> "The terms are defined to be those expressions that can be built up
>   from the constant symbols and the variables by prefixing the function
>   symbols."

In this definition, I think that "the constant symbols and the variables" is not appropriate. It must be "the constant symbols or the variables".

What do you think?

Comment: "And" is OK. Think about $f(x,2)$.

Comment: Enderton is in fact describing a *recursive* construction. So, a term might also be 'built up' from other terms, as in $f(g(y),f(x,2))$. But it all *starts* (base step) with terms that are either constant symbols or variables.

Comment: Your concern is not wrong, but it seems to me only a "linguistic" issue. We can say that *terms* are built-up from a "box" of basic elements containing both constants and variables (this explains the "and"). But this "box" is the set-union of the sub-boxes of constants and variables, and those are "joined" by the union operation (this explains the "or"). A formal definition is : The set $TERM$ is the smallest set satisfying the condition : 1. any variable is a term; 2. any constant symbol is a term; 3. if $f$ is an $n$-palce function symbol ... Neither "or" nor "and".

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA Three things. First: *terms* are built-up from constant symbols, variables "and" other terms, via the use of functional symbols (you can't scape formulating Enderton's definition recursively). Second: your set *TERM* satisfies 1 "and" 2 "and" 3 ("and" the condition that it should be the smallest set simultaneously satisfying these three conditions). Third: Enderton's *bottom-up* definition of *TERM* via closure is perfectly formal; your *top-down* definition is in fact *equivalent* to it.

Answer (score 1):

I think "and" is appropriate. If $c$ is a constant and we have a binary function $f$, then $f(c,x)$ is a valid term, where we use both a constant and a variable.

Comment: I understand that "and" is appropriate. However, I don't understand why "or" is not appropriate.

Comment: This was not your question!

Answer (score 0):

### ANSWER 1

Here is a common mistake regarding *recursive definitions*. Imagine you want to define factorial, and set:

[base step] $n! = 1$, if $n=0$

[recursive step] $n! = n(n-1)!$, if $n>0$

Now, while it is true, when talking about the factorial of $n$, that *either* you are to deal with the base step (in case $m$ happens to be $0$) *or* you are to deal with the inductive step (in case $m$ happens to be greater than $0$), it is important to notice that *both* steps describe true facts about factorials. Accordingly, one might use logic to specify the behavior of the factorial function by writing:
$$(\forall n)((n=0\to n!=1)\land(n>0\to n!=n(n-1)!))$$
Replacing $\land$ (*and*) by $\lor$ (*or*) in the above sentence would result in an assertion that would be true, for instance, for any operation $f$ that were to satisfy *only one* of those steps. Indeed, the expression $n=0\to f(n)=1$ is true, for instance, if $f$ is exponentiation having the argument $n$ as its power and any fixed constant $c$ in its base (as $f(0)=c^0=1$, for any constant $c$). But exponentiation obviously does not coincide with factorial (the latter grows faster!).

---

### ANSWER 2

Unintentionally swapping *or* for *and* is more common than one might imagine.
Imagine you want to describe the behavior of the typical **conditional statement**

`IF` b `THEN` do *this* `ELSE` do *that*

in your preferred programming language.

In that case *both* the following instructions are expected to be implemented:

(1) If the boolean condition evaluates to `true`, *this* should be done.

(2) If the boolean condition evaluates to `false`, *that* should be done.

Even in case *this* and *that* are alternatives that exclude each other, a conditional statement that altered the control flow according to *only one* of the above instructions could hardly be said to implement the standard `IF-THEN-ELSE`! So, again, we're not talking about *either* (1) *or* (2) being true about an execution, but *both*.